# Trying If statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This if statement doesn't work.

can anybody tell why the code below doesn't work, and help me fix?

```
i=0;

while(1)
{
   if(counter2 < storeanother[0].size())
      break;

 int j=0;

  while(1)
 {
   if(j < handler)
      break;

     outputFile2 << storeanother[0][counter2] << "   +   " << storeanother[1][counter2] << " =   " << z80[i].get(j) << endl;
     counter2+=1;

      j++;
 }
 i++;
}
   outputFile2.close();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what is the result at this point? And most of all, in the first For loop, why are you testing with 'counter2' instead of 'i'? And in the second part, why are you using while loops instead of For loops?

Comment: … and how all that "code" relates to C++11?

Comment: you are doing i++ and j ++too late. It's a post increment and could be done earlier when you strat the while loop

Answer (score 2):

You invert the condition

```
for (init; cond, post) { body;}
```

is equivalent to

```
init;
while (true) {
    if (!cond) { // and not simply cond
        break;
    }
    body;
    post;
}
```

or even

```
init;
while (cond) {
    body;
    post;
}
```

So

```
if(counter2 < storeanother[0].size())
    break;
```

should be

```
if (counter2 >= storeanother[0].size())
    break;
```

and similar for the other loop.

Answer (score 1):

you break the while with the wrong condition, you have to reverse it. For example :

```
if(j == handler)
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

because in for loop when condition gets true then only loop runs
 and here you have made the condition true in both the cases so its just breaking from the loop
change it to opposite and it will work fine.

like this way:

```
i=0;
// for (int i = 0; counter2 < storeanother[0].size(); i++)
while(1)
{
   if(counter2 >= storeanother[0].size())
      break;

 int j=0;
 //for (j = 0; j < handler; j++)
  while(1)
 {
   if(j >= handler)
      break;

     outputFile2 << storeanother[0][counter2] << "   +   " << storeanother[1][counter2] << " =   " << z80[i].get(j) << endl;
     counter2+=1;

      j++;
 }
 i++;
}
   outputFile2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the if conditions are wrong as mentioned by others, I don't see any reason here to have

```
while(1)
{
    if(j >= handler)
        break;
    // do the stuff
```

instead of

```
while(j < handler)
{
    // do the stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to do this:

```
int i=0;
while(counter2 < storeanother[0].size())
{

    for (int j = 0; j < handler; j++)
    {
        outputFile2 << storeanother[0][counter2] << "   +   " <<streanother[1][counter2] << " =   " << z80[i].get(j) << endl;
        counter2+=1;
    }
    i++;
}
outputFile2.close();
```

And for the second part:

```
i=0;
// for (int i = 0; counter2 < storeanother[0].size(); i++)
while(counter2 < storeanother[0].size()))
{

 int j=0;
 //for (j = 0; j < handler; j++)
  while(j < handler)
 {
     outputFile2 << storeanother[0][counter2] << "   +   " << storeanother[1][counter2] << " =   " << z80[i].get(j) << endl;
     counter2+=1;

      j++;
 }
 i++;
}
   outputFile2.close();
```